# Time series classification MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network, time-series, classification

My task is to classify time-series data with use of MATLAB and any neural-network framework.

Describing task more specifically:
Is is a problem from computer-vision field. Is is a scene boundary detection task.

Source data are 4 arrays of neighbouring frame histogram correlations from the videoflow.
Based on this data, we have to classify this timeseries with 2 classes:

- "scene break"
- "no scene break"

So network input is 4 double values for each source data entry, and output is one binary value. I am going to show example of src data below:

```
0.997894,0.999413,0.982098,0.992164
0.998964,0.999986,0.999127,0.982068
0.993807,0.998823,0.994008,0.994299
0.225917,0.000000,0.407494,0.400424
0.881150,0.999427,0.949031,0.994918
```

Problem is that pattern-recogition tools from Matlab Neural Toolbox (like patternnet) threat source data like independant entrues. But I have strong belief that results will be precise only if net take decision based on the history of previous correlations.

But I also did not manage to get valid response from reccurent nets which serve time series analysis (like delaynet and narxnet).

narxnet and delaynet return lousy result and it looks like these types of networks not supposed to solve classification tasks. I am not insert any code here while it is allmost totally autogenerated with use of Matlab Neural Toolbox GUI.

I would apprecite any help. Especially, some advice which tool fits better for accomplishing my task.

Comment: add previous steps data as additional inputs...

Comment: @Dan, thank you for response. But i am not sure that it is possible to  set weights for additional inputs. So, If we processing n entry, values from n-1 should have more impact than n-10 and less impact than values from n. I thought that there is some special type of network for such a task.

Comment: you probably don't need n-10 data, this depends on the system you are trying to model of course. Start by providing all t = n and t = n - 1 data as inputs. Then try add t = n - 2. If this doesn't results in a noticeable improvement then you only need to go as far back as t - n. But chances are you can model it as a first order system and thus you'll only need n and n-1 data as inputs.

Comment: @Dan, This neural network is being developed to use for this classification task instead of the adaptiveThreshold (previous solution). Tests showed that max precision I gain with sliding window size = 30. So, I am sure that for my task is need n-10 data and possibly even more.

Comment: I am working on "pattern recognition of time-series rainfall data "... and newbie in matlab... would you please provide me matlab code of your program... i am pretty sure that it will help me alott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how difficult to classify this problem.
Given your sample, 4 input and 1 output feed-forward neural network is sufficient.

If you insist on using historical inputs, you simply pre-process your input `d`, such that

Your new input `D(t)` (a vector at time `t`) is composed of `d(t)` is a 1x4 vector at time `t`; `d(t-1)` is 1x4 vector at time `t-1`;... and `d(t-k)` is a 1x4 vector at time `t-k`.

If `t-k <0`, just treat it as '0'.

So you have a  1x(4(k+1)) vector as input, and 1 output. 
Similar as Dan mentioned, you need to find a good `k`.

Speaking of the weights, I think additional pre-processing like windowing method on the input is not necessary, since neural network would be trained to assign weights to each input dimension.

It sounds a bit messy, since the neural network would consider each input dimension independently. That means you lose the information as four neighboring correlations.

One possible solution is the pre-processing **extracts** the neighborhood features, e.g. using **mean** and **std** as two features representative for the originals.

Comment: Thank you. While You and Dan have the same view about possible approaches, I am going to agree with you and implement network according to your advices.